# Why SharePoint is not considering 'dbo.AuditData' table while calculating the site-collection size?

Tags: administration, 2007, database, configuration

We have a heavy used site collection with a 30GB quota limit on the content DB - WSS_WebApp_Content1, I have verified the 'dbo.AuditData' table and found that it has 1.4c records and is 35 GB in size.

Why SharePoint is not considering 'dbo.AuditData' table while calculating the site-collection size? and what are all the other tables treated like this ?

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A site collection quota is set to manage content in a site collection.  There are tables in the database that store things other than content.  The Audit Data is one example of that, in addition there are some user information tables.

Comment: As the 'dbo.AuditData' table occupies more than 35GB, we are facing some SQL issues. can we set a quota kind of setting against this table to restrict the auto growth &  would be the your suggestion for me now?

Comment: You can do normal DBA things in SQL Server to adjust the autogrowth properties.  You can also look at adjusting the audit settings in SharePoint so that less data is retained.

Comment: If we enable audit for all possible events, does the stored procedure 'proc_AddAuditEntry' be executed at the moment when user perform any action?

I know, the answer is 'Yes', still would like to confirm.

we are facing DB deadlock issue due 'proc_AddAuditEntry', do you have any suggestion for me.

Comment: I would strongly suggest Mike's suggestion of looking at the audit settings to see what's retained. If you have Auditing enabled your business will have that as a requirement, and they must state what is to be retained and for how long. Once that requirement is set in stone, your Database requirement becomes a prerequisite for that to happen. If you run out of storage, that requirement should be enough of a reason to buy more storage. Out of curiosity, how many users are accessing the site at the same time, in order for the deadlocks to occur?